# How to remove/trim spaces or tabs while writing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, text, keydown

I'm trying to trim a String using javascript (in jQuery) while the user is writing:

```
$(document).on('keydown', "input[type='text'], textarea", function(e) {
            $(this).val( $(this).val().trim() );
            console.log('fixing');
        //if ($(this).val() == "") {
            //alert('gwo!');
        //}
    } );
```

But the problem here is when the user writes a space to write another word, this code trims the data in the input and the next word is concatenated like:

I'mbigandgreat

Really what I need is to remove the tabs or the spaces when the user texts using CTRL+V from clipboard.

Can you help?

Comment: Use the [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste) event instead of `keydown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. Look for repeated space chars. Preserve the last one and remove others. String.replace with RegExp can handle this.

Also I used keyup event instead of keydown

```js
$(document).on('keyup', "input[type='text'], textarea", function(e) {
  let val = $(this).val();
  val = val.replace(/(?:^\s+|\s+?(\s))(\S+)/g, "$1$2");
  val = val.replace(/\s+(\s)$/, "$1"); 
  $(this).val( val );
 } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: this is good, but it not includes the case of \t, may be: `val.replace(/\s+?(\s)(\t)(\S+)/g, "$1$2");` ??? it's right?

Comment: @Cristian \s includes all space characters (\n," ",\t... etc)

Comment: Try it with: ' \t\t\t  asasdas asdasaas     \t\t\t     ' it will let the tabs still there. With '     this is only what i want here    \t  ' a one space is present at first.

Comment: Answer is updated. That works for all cases. And this snippet not converts the tabs to spaces. It only removes repeated spaces and leaves the last one

Answer (score 0):

Is it even necessary to trim it on the client? If it's important, then you're going to need to do it on the serve anyway, so you might just be able to leave it there.